# If a JButton is clicked change current frame, how can i do it?

Tags: java, jbutton

I´m a beginner in Java or Programming in general, and i´m trying to make a program that works as a calculator to things like Sigma notation, Pythagoras theorem... 
But as a "noob" i am at programming, i need help.

Well, i have a menu to choose the kind of "calculator" you want, and i have some JButtons. How can i make so that when one of those buttons is clicked, change what is showing in the frame. Like if button1 is clicked, in the frame it would appear a different menu? i don´t know if i made myself clear, but i hope you could help me.

Comment: Learn to walk before you run. I recommend the [Oracle tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: Use a CardLayout. Please google the tutorial -- first hit.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your patience. I actually got it. And thank you for the recommendation.